# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \frac {\sin x}{x} \,dx$ using Simpson's $\frac {1}{3}$ rule and $\frac {3}{8}$ rule with $n=6$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi \frac {\sin x}{x}\,dx$   using Simpson's $\dfrac {1}{3}$ rule and $\dfrac {3}{8}$ rule with $n=6$.

For $n=6$, $h=\dfrac {\pi - 0}{6}=\dfrac {\pi}{6}$.

But, the value of $f(x)=\dfrac {\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0,\pi$ takes $\dfrac {0}{0}$ form. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin x }{x},& x \ne 0\\ 1, & x=0 \end{cases},
$$

which is continuous  in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: We are required to use $f(x)=1$ at $x=0, \pi$. Is it?

Comment: You have a typo in your comment : that limit is 1, not 0

Comment: Only at $x=0$. Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} =1$, we simply define $f(0)=1$. At $x=\pi$, $f$ is already well defined and you just compute $f(\pi) = \frac{\sin \pi}{\pi} = \frac{0}{\pi} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks @GBat I "corrected" the comment.